# Create Rails project structure without installing full Rails stack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I use rvm for development.  In order to create a new Rails project directory initially, I will install the full Rails stack of gems in my default gemset so I can run "rails new".  I then will create the ".ruby-version" and ".ruby-gemset" files in the new project directory so rvm can automatically switch me the proper ruby version and gemset when navigating into the project.  I then have to install the full Rails stack again in the project's gemset.  So I never really end up using my Rails stack installed in my default gemset (except to run "rails new").

So is there a subset of the Rails gems which I can install just to run the equivalent of "rails new" to generate the new project?  Is there something else I can use to do the same, but is technically outside of Rails?

Comment: Theoretically, all you need is rails generators, but good luck trying to extract them from rails in a runnable form.

Comment: Also, why do you still use gemsets when you have bundler?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev So I can quickly switch between project without having to reinstall gems.  Is there some capability of bundler which allows me to do that?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev regarding the extraction of the rails generators, if that's where project generation is implemented, then agreed.  I was hoping they use some simple script (packaged in it's own independent Ruby gem) that I could install and run on it's own.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what bundler does. You can install any gem versions in the system (gems from all your projects) and then bundler makes sure to load the exact versions that this current project requires. No need to uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev but how does that work with different ruby versions?  Don't some gems compile against the current ruby version when installed?

Comment: I myself use chruby and with this setup, each ruby version gets its own gem list, even those gems that theoretically could be shared between rubies. Within the same ruby version, bundler rules the version resolution.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I've never used chruby, but looking it up just now, it's not really clear to me that it has any different functionality than rvm.  Also I don't see how it answers my last question.  The situation is you have two different projects that run on two different Ruby versions, but use the same version of a particular gem.  Are you sure that having a single gem installation will guarantee that both projects will run properly?  I'd rather not find out.  I prefer to keep the gem installations separate between projects.

Either way, this is getting outside the scope of the question.

Comment: chruby is just a ruby switcher, with __way__ less functionality than rvm. Which is itself a feature. (less functionality -> less code -> less bugs).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to specify when creating the rails project which portions of the Rails stack to include/exclude, but once it's installed you can choose which portions to not import into your application by modifying your `application.rb` file.

Your `application.rb` file contains the following code:

```
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "action_cable/engine"
require "sprockets/railtie"
require "dotenv-rails"
```

Simply comment out the frameworks you don't want to include in your running application and they won't be imported.

Not sure if this is what you're looking for or not, hope it helps though.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This isn't quite what I'm looking for.  I'm looking for some way to initially create the Rails project without installing the full Rails stack.  Ideally, it would be something like install one gem which allows me to call a basic "rails new".

Comment: @Rossman Yea, unfortunately I'm unaware of anything similar to what you're looking to do there. Sorry I couldn't be of more help!